# I have a UITextField for customCell for UITableView. On TapGesture of UITextField, I need to display checkmark on right side of UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview

I have a UITextField for customCell for UITableView. 
On TapGesture of UITextField, I need to display checkmark on right side of UITableViewCell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

PreferenceCellWithTextBox *cell = (PreferenceCellWithTextBox *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PreferenceCellIdentifier"];

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PreferenceCellWithTextBox"
        owner:nil
        options:nil];

    for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
    {
        if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        {

            cell=(PreferenceCellWithTextBox *)currentObject;
            break;
        }
    }

    if([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }


        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(forwardToDidSelect:)];
        [cell.userIdTextField addGestureRecognizer:tap];

}

return cell;
}
```

Here, I am writing for Tap Gesture. and It gets called only once. It should not happen like that. It should get called whenever I may touch UITextField which is on UITableViewCell.

```
 -(void)forwardToDidSelect:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tap
{

[self tableView:self.userIdSuggestiontableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];

}
```

Here, I have written code for did select row. On Select of any row, I want to display the Checkmark.and remove checkmark from previous one.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


if(self.checkedIndexPath)

{
    PreferenceCellWithTextBox* uncheckCell =(PreferenceCellWithTextBox *) [tableView
                                    cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.checkedIndexPath];

    uncheckCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

}
if([self.checkedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath])

{
    self.checkedIndexPath = nil;
}
else
{

    PreferenceCellWithTextBox* cell = (PreferenceCellWithTextBox*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];



    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    self.checkedIndexPath = indexPath;


}

}
```

Comment: Again, no mention of what you have tried so far. I'm sorry but you ain't gonna get any help like this.

Comment: Hi Sufian, I have added the code.